# Inject a object in NancyFX module

Tags: nancy, tinyioc

I am trying to use Nancy as self-hosted in a legacy application, so I am trying to change as little as possible.

My Nancy's modules need to interact with a instance of a object previously constructed that, from the point of view of Nancy is like a singleton. I am guarantee that the same instance will exists during all the lifetime of the Nancy server.

My questions is, how can I use this instance inside my modules? Thanks in advance for any help or reference.

Answer (score 0):

Is this object instance created through a dependency container in the legacy app?

Comment: No, The legacy app does not use a container. It is just a object instantiated at app initialization and given as constructor parameter, to several other clases. I already solved the issue creating a singleton and sharing this object through the singleton.